# How to pass C# objects through to JNI method in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin and need to call through to two static java methods in a jar I've linked to. Here is the java class in the jar:

```
package com.test;

public class Car {
    public static Car makeCar(String name);
    public void drawCar(ImageView imageview);
}
```

I'm not sure how to pass in the parameters for the two methods to the JNI code. The JNIEnv.Call**Method() class takes a JValue[] array for parameters, I'm trying to use it to wrap a C# string and call it all like so:

```
// C#

string carName = "mustang";

JValue[] paramCarName = new JValue[] {
    new JValue(JNIEnv.NewString(carName))
};

IntPtr theClass = JNIEnv.FindClass("com.test.Car");
IntPtr theMethod = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(theClass, 
    "makeCar", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
IntPtr resultCar = JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod(
    theClass, theMethod, paramCarName);
```

Is that correct usage? I'm having the same problem with calling the second method, which refers to a C# version of android's ImageView:

```
// C#

// Xamarin provides an ImageView wrapper class.
ImageView imageview = ...;

// Is it alright to use JNIEnv.ToJniHandle here to reference the imageview?
JValue[] paramCarName = new JValue[] {
    new JValue (JNIEnv.ToJniHandle (imageview))
};

...
```

The above currently compiles ok, but I can't run it since I only have the free version. Any info on this would be great as I'm sure I'm misusing this.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by the "jar I've linked to."? Did you go through the process of creating a Java Binding Library to add a C# wrapper around the Java code you are trying to call?

Comment: No I am trying to avoid a Java Binding Library. I tried using Xamarin Studio and it resulted in many errors (it's a larger jar than in my example). I was hoping I could include the jar with the app distribution, and just call the two methods I need via JNI, without having to make the Java Binding Library.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having trouble getting a jar to bind you may be able to fix the errors with Transforms/Metadata.xml (documentation [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)/)). With that file you can suppress bindings for classes or entire packages that cause code generation issues.

If Metadata.xml cannot get the job done, another (less desirable) option is to create your own Java library that wraps the one that won't bind, and exposes only the methods you need to access from C#. Then bind that jar.

But, it sounds like you have the free version of Xamarin (probably why you are trying to avoid jar binding since that requires the paid version) so I'll attempt to fix your JNI code:

```
// C#

IntPtr classHandle;
IntPtr theClass = JNIEnv.FindClass("com/test/Car", classHandle);
IntPtr theMethod = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(theClass, 
    "makeCar", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
// Just create a new JValue with your C# Android object peer
JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod(classRef, methodRef, new JValue[] {
        new JValue(imageView)
    });
```

My JNI is not super-advanced so take the above with some grains of salt. But according to code generated by Xamarin Studio for jar binding, the above should be (close to) correct.

Comment: Hi Brett, thanks for the info - yes I updated to a trial version of Xamarin studio and can finally compile and run this code. Everything is working now except the method where I try passing in the C# ImageView peer as a JValue. The app will just crash with a (SIGABRT). Do you have any documentation that talks about passing a C# peer view through to JNI land? Thanks

Comment: It looks like `CallStaticObjectMethod` takes an array of JValues that could be the problem. I'll update my answer with the correct call.

Comment: Hey Brett, sorry yeah I had been using an array of JValue[] like you have in the updated answer, which is still causing the crash. I'm not quite sure how Xamarin would even expose its version of an ImageView to dalvik as its notion of an ImageView. Should the two even be compatible in this way via JNI? I've been searching endlessly for an example of trying to pass a view from Xamarin to a jar via JNI but have found nothing. Have you seen any docs on this topic from the Xamarin team?